# Remove lines from a text file which do not contain a certain string with python

Tags: python, string, text, file-io, file

I am trying to form a quotes file of a specific user name in a log file.  How do I remove every line that does not contain the specific user name in it?  Or how do I write all the lines which contain this user name to a new file?

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as rfp:
  with open('output.txt', 'w') as wfp:
    for line in rfp:
      if ilikethis(line):
        wfp.write(line)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
with open(logfile) as f_in:
    lines = [l for l in f_in if username in l]
with open(outfile, 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.writelines(lines)
```

Or if you don't want to store all the lines in memory

```
with open(logfile) as f_in:
    lines = (l for l in f_in if username in l)
    with open(outfile, 'w') as f_out:
        f_out.writelines(lines)
```

I sort of like the first one better but for a large file, it might drag.

Comment: You don't need to indent the second 'with' in the second case, for the same reason that you don't need to in the first case.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel I do actually. Because in the second case I'm using a generator expression, the file will be closed and it will cause an error when the generator expression actually gets processed if the `with` statement exits. Try it. It's the only gotcha that I can think of for using generator expressions with file processing.

Comment: Ah, I see. The existence of the generator won't keep the file open. Silly me :)

Answer (score 2):

Something along this line should suffice:

```
newfile = open(newfilename, 'w')
for line in file(filename, 'r'):
    if name in line:
        newfile.write(line)
newfile.close()
```

See :  http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

f.readlines() returns a list containing all the lines of data in the file.

An alternative approach to reading lines is to loop over the file object. This is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simpler code

```
>>> for line in f:
        print line
```

Also you can checkout the use of `with` keyword. The advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes

```
>>> with open(filename, 'r') as f:
...     read_data = f.read()
>>> f.closed
True
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for python, but if you're on unix this is a job for grep.

```
grep name file
```

If you're not on unix, well... the answer above does the trick :)